# Cant get the value from openweathermap api

Tags: json, laravel

I try to produce a value from openweathermap Api but it show an error : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Here is my Controller

```
 public function getRemoteData(){

    $response = Http::get('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pasir Gudang&units=metric');

    return view('welcome')->with('response', json_decode($response, true));
}
```

and here my view right now

```
@if(isset($response))
            @foreach($response as $row)
                city: {{ $row->name }}
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

Comment: thanks.. now it shows another error : Undefined index

Comment: array:13 [▼
  "coord" => array:2 [▶]
  "weather" => array:1 [▶]
  "base" => "stations"
  "main" => array:6 [▶]
  "visibility" => 10000
  "wind" => array:2 [▶]
  "clouds" => array:1 [▶]
  "dt" => 1588496627
  "sys" => array:5 [▶]
  "timezone" => 28800
  "id" => 1880252
  "name" => "Pasir Gudang"
  "cod" => 200
]

Comment: it cannot identify sys index